# Get all Jetpacks iOS has on Android

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Is it possible to get all the jetpacks iOS version has on Android?
iOS has around 3 more, not to mention more eye-candy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possibility to get the ones which are only available on iOS, is to hope they will include them in a update for the Android version.

Comment: Ah, so there's no way to unlock them somehow during gameplay?

Comment: I dont think so, because they just arent in the Android version, so theres no chance to unlock them